# keyword can't be an expression when assigning an argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Hello I have this method called save_schedule that takes some arguments (transport_id, departure_id, etc) to be saved to the database. but when I ran the code I got this following error

```
    newSchedule = TravelScheduleDetailRepository(self.transport_id=transport_id, self.transport_type=transport_type, self.transport_company_name=transport_company_name, self.departure_city_id=departure_city_id, self.departure_country_id=departure_country_id, self.destination_city_id=destination_city_id, self.destination_country_id=destination_country_id, self.departure_date=departure_date, self.available_seat=available_seat)
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

I still can't find on how to correctly assign the arguments.

here's my code :

```
def save_travel_schedule(self, transport_id, transport_type, transport_company_name, departure_city_id, departure_country_id, destination_city_id, destination_country_id, departure_date, available_seat):
    newSchedule = TravelScheduleDetailRepository(self.transport_id=transport_id, self.transport_type=transport_type, self.transport_company_name=transport_company_name, self.departure_city_id=departure_city_id, self.departure_country_id=departure_country_id, self.destination_city_id=destination_city_id, self.destination_country_id=destination_country_id, self.departure_date=departure_date, self.available_seat=available_seat)
    session.add(newSchedule)
    session.commit()
```

any help would be appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got the order wrong.

`self.transport_type=transport_type` should be `transport_type=self.tranport_type`, not the other way around.

Same for all the other parameters.

Comment: That gives me `TypeError: filter() got an unexpected keyword argument` since transport_type is a variable I define...

Answer (score 0):

The keyword arguments in the `TravelScheduleDetailRepository` class do not require the reference to the instance: `self.`

Removing `self.` from all the keyword arguments should fix your problem.

`self` is only used when you are referring to a property or method in an instance.